# Calling a Private Sub/Event in Thisworkbook from Module 1 Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hope everyone is doing good.

I have `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)` in Thisworkbook module and I would like to call this from my Module code `Sub Mail_it()`.

So in simple, If I call from `Sub Mail_it()`, then `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)` should run/execute.

Please help and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)` is an event callback function built into Excel. You shouldn't call that subroutine directly.

Instead, make a new subroutine with your function, `MyNewSub`. Put all the code logic in there. Then call the new subroutine from both `Sub Mail_it` and `Sub Workbook_AfterSave`.

EDIT: adding example code to illustrate. The first block is in `ThisWorkbook`

```
' Only Excel should call this Sub
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call MyNewSub
End Sub
```

This code is in `Module 1`

```
' Your application calls this sub    
Sub Mail_it()
    Call MyNewSub
End Sub

Sub MyNewSub()
    ' Here is where your code goes
End Sub
```

You can move the subs to different files, or give them different names if you want.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I would need that `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)` to work whenever my workbook is saved and also I need to call from my Macro from Module. Is this possible? Please Suggest.

Comment: Yes, they would both call the same subroutine - let me update the answer with code in a minute.

Comment: Ok, check out the updates. Of course this is 100% simplified version. You probably have extra code that goes inside `Mail_it` and maybe different code inside `AfterSave`. But you can figure those out :p